# CSS spinner/loading icon does not display on Safari/iPhone

Tags: ios, html, css

I am developing a mobile web application, and need to incorporate a loading spinner.

I have found one from a helpful website, and works on IE, FF and Chrome, but for some reason does not work on Safari on my iPhone 4.

HTML:

```
<div class="overlay">
    <div class="loader">
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.overlay {
    opacity:    0.5; 
    background: #000; 
    width:      100%;
    height:     100%; 
    z-index:    10;
    top:        0; 
    left:       0; 
    position:   fixed;
}
.loader {
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  margin: 50vh auto;
  /*position: relative;*/
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: -100px;
}

.loader > div {
  width: 6px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  left: -10px;
  bottom: 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transform-origin: 10px 35px;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  animation: loader 0.8s infinite;
}
.loader > div:nth-child(2) {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  animation-delay: 0.1s;
}
.loader > div:nth-child(3) {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  animation-delay: 0.2s;
}
.loader > div:nth-child(4) {
  transform: rotate(135deg);
  animation-delay: 0.3s;
}
.loader > div:nth-child(5) {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  animation-delay: 0.4s;
}
.loader > div:nth-child(6) {
  transform: rotate(225deg);
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
}
.loader > div:nth-child(7) {
  transform: rotate(270deg);
  animation-delay: 0.6s;
}
.loader > div:nth-child(8) {
  transform: rotate(315deg);
  animation-delay: 0.7s;
}

@keyframes loader {
  0% {
    background: transparent;
    left: -10px;
    transform-origin: 10px 35px;
  }
  30% {
    background: white;
  }
  100% {
    background: transparent;
    left: 10px;
    transform-origin: -10px 35px;
  }
}
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/ztBL6TN03yx41t4PRZMM?p=preview

Comment: It's probably because you're missing vendor prefixes. Also, your code isn't working for me in Chrome. My guess is you need to add `-webkit` prefixes where appropriate.

Comment: @rnevius - thanks, where should these prefixes go?

Comment: Updated Plunk- http://plnkr.co/edit/ztBL6TN03yx41t4PRZMM?p=preview

Comment: Is it still not working in Safari?

Comment: Cool, glad you got it working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution required prefixes, e.g:

```
.loader > div {
  width: 6px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  left: -10px;
  bottom: 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 10px 35px;
  -moz-transform-origin: 10px 35px;
  -ms-transform-origin: 10px 35px;
  -o-transform-origin: 10px 35px;
  transform-origin: 10px 35px;

  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);

  -webkit-animation: loader 0.8s infinite;
  -moz-animation: loader 0.8s infinite;
  animation: loader 0.8s infinite;
}

/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes loader {
    0% {
    background: transparent;
    left: -10px;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 10px 35px;
    -moz-transform-origin: 10px 35px;
    transform-origin: 10px 35px;
  }
  30% {
    background: white;
  }
  100% {
    background: transparent;
    left: 10px;
    -webkit-transform-origin: -10px 35px;
    -moz-transform-origin: -10px 35px;
    transform-origin: -10px 35px;
  }
}
```

Plunkr: plnkr.co/edit/ztBL6TN03yx41t4PRZMM?p=preview